# mouseup, mouse down not working in android webview

Tags: android-webview

Following jquery is not working in my android webview. When long press on a span for more than 10 seconds it needs to be redirected to a specific url, this is working on site but not working on android webview.

```
$(function() {
  var longpress = 10000;
  var start;

  jQuery("#restart").on('mousedown', function(e) {
    start = new Date().getTime();
  });

  jQuery("#restart").on('mouseleave', function(e) {
    start = 0;
  });

  jQuery("#restart").on('mouseup', function(e) {
    if (new Date().getTime() >= (start + longpress)) {
      alert('long press!');
      $("#restart >a").attr("href", "http://siteurl/?key=gesture")
    } else {
      alert('short press!');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using a touchscreen? If so you may need to use 'touchstart' and 'touchend'

Comment: works like charm.. thanks pal.. where did you get that? Can you give me a link for the documentation?

Comment: The touch events docs can be found on MDN. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively use   `touchstart`, `touchleave` and `touchend`

```js
$(function() {
  var longpress = 10000;
  var start;

  jQuery("#restart").on('mousedown touchstart', function(e) {
    start = new Date().getTime();
  });

  jQuery("#restart").on('mouseleave touchleave', function(e) {
    start = 0;
  });

  jQuery("#restart").on('mouseup touchend', function(e) {
    if (new Date().getTime() >= (start + longpress)) {
      alert('long press!');
      $("#restart >a").attr("href", "http://siteurl/?key=gesture")
    } else {
      alert('short press!');
    }
  });
});
```