# In browser and electron platform, painting works, but in android platform trying to draw on canvas does not, why is this?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, canvas

As I asked in the question, in a cordova app, in browser and electron platform, painting works, but in android platform trying to draw on canvas does not. Clicking on canvas, instead of drawing, I drag the screen.

The code follows.

Here is the html:

```
       <div class="centerPainting">

            <h1>Painting: hold down the mouse button to draw in the rectangle below.</h1><div id="container"><canvas id="imageView" width="300" height="300">
                    <p>Unfortunately, your platform does not support the canvas element.</p>

                </canvas>

            </div>

        </div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#container { 
  position: relative; 
}

#imageView { 
  border: 1px solid #000; 
}

.centerPainting {

    margin: auto;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 10px;

    /* The CSS below stops users from being able to select text. */
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */        
    -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
    -ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+/Edge */
    user-select: none; /* Standard */

}
```

Here is the Javascript:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    
    var canvas, context, tool;  
    
    init();
}

  function init () {
    // Find the canvas element.
    canvas = document.getElementById('imageView');
    if (!canvas) {
      alert('Error: I cannot find the canvas element!');
      return;
    }

    if (!canvas.getContext) {
      alert('Error: no canvas.getContext!');
      return;
    }

    // Get the 2D canvas context.
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    if (!context) {
      alert('Error: failed to getContext!');
      return;
    }

    // Pencil tool instance.
    tool = new tool_pencil();

    // Attach the mousedown, mousemove and mouseup event listeners.
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', ev_canvas, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', ev_canvas, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup',   ev_canvas, false);
  }

  // This painting tool works like a drawing pencil which tracks the mouse 
  // movements.
  function tool_pencil () {
    var tool = this;
    this.started = false;

    // This is called when you start holding down the mouse button.
    // This starts the pencil drawing.
    this.mousedown = function (ev) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(ev._x, ev._y);
        tool.started = true;
    };

    // This function is called every time you move the mouse. Obviously, it only 
    // draws if the tool.started state is set to true (when you are holding down 
    // the mouse button).
    this.mousemove = function (ev) {
      if (tool.started) {
        context.lineTo(ev._x, ev._y);
        context.stroke();
      }
    };

    // This is called when you release the mouse button.
    this.mouseup = function (ev) {
      if (tool.started) {
        tool.mousemove(ev);
        tool.started = false;
      }
    };
  }

  // The general-purpose event handler. This function just determines the mouse 
  // position relative to the canvas element.
  function ev_canvas (ev) {
    if (ev.layerX || ev.layerX == 0) { // Firefox
      ev._x = ev.layerX;
      ev._y = ev.layerY;
    } else if (ev.offsetX || ev.offsetX == 0) { // Opera
      ev._x = ev.offsetX;
      ev._y = ev.offsetY;
    }

    // Call the event handler of the tool.
    var func = tool[ev.type];
    if (func) {
      func(ev);
    }
  }
```

How do I fix that?

Update: After Morrison Chang's comment, I changed my code to:

```
    // Attach the mousedown, mousemove and mouseup event listeners.
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown touchstart', ev_canvas, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove touchmove', ev_canvas, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup touchend',   ev_canvas, false);
```

But it still does not work.

Update 2: I added multiple event listeners, as this developer did:

[adding multiple event listeners to one element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11845678/adding-multiple-event-listeners-to-one-element)

So, I added this code:

```
    // Attach the touchstart, touchmove and touchend event listeners.
    canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', ev_canvas, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', ev_canvas, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('touchend',   ev_canvas, false);
```

and this code:

```
    this.touchstart = function (ev) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(ev._x, ev._y);
        tool.started = true;
    }; 

    this.touchmove = function (ev) {
      if (tool.started) {
        context.lineTo(ev._x, ev._y);
        context.stroke();
      }
    };

    this.touchend = function (ev) {
      if (tool.started) {
        tool.mousemove(ev);
        tool.started = false;
      }
    };
```

But still, it doesn't work.

Comment: See: [mouseup, mouse down not working in android webview](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41979039/295004)

Comment: I think the answer you saw is using jQuery features, please research multiple listeners in Javascript.

Comment: `Maybe try "canvas{touch-action:none;}"`

Comment: Someone_who_likes_SE, that did not work. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

A couple things to check:

- Try adding an alert in your ev_canvas() method, to see if the code is reaching there on your touch events.
- You mentioned that the screen is being dragged. You might want to set the viewport to not move in your `index.html`, if you haven't already done so:

  `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, viewport-fit=cover">`